# Logstash Add Extra Space on a particular field based on the config

Tags: ruby, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I have a particular requirement where I have extracted out a field based on the GROK patterns. And based on the length of the attribute, i have to add `space` at the end of the string.

For example:

Attribute:

```
PartA: test
PartB: abc
```

Output Should be like:

```
test#####abc##
```

Where the requirement says `partA` should be of length `10` and `partB` should be of length `5`. So if you see, I have added extra space (`#`) based on the current length of the attribute.

I am currently trying to create a new line based on the output above requirement,

here is the attempt (logstash.conf):

```
file {
   path => "/Users/Smit/Downloads/chrome/observability/logstash_dump.txt"
   codec => line { format => "%{PartA}#####${PartB}###"}
  }
 }
```

Is there a way to dynamically append space (`#` used this for clarity) instead of hardcoding.

Here is the full Logstash file: https://dpaste.org/dsuH